# Incluir uma bibliioteca no vscode (linux)

Tags: linux, visual-studio

Por muito tempo usei uma versão alternativa do conio para linux [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V119IzUgwJw), mas por algum motivo o vscode não está mais "achando" o arquivo conio.h que é copiado para /usr/include. Tentei incluir esse path no c_cpp_properties.json, mas sem sucesso. No fim, consegui voltar a utilizar a biblioteca da seguinte maneira

#include<stdio.h>
#include "/home/conio.h"

Porém, é uma gambiarra muito feia que gostaria de resolver. Queria voltar a usar #include<conio.h> ou pelo menos #include "conio.h". Como fazer isso?

Answer (score -3):

Ao invés incluir o arquivo conio.h diretamente no código, é só usar funções padrões da biblioteca do C, pode ser a <stdio.h> ou a <stdlib.h>.
Tem várias funções iguais a do conio.h, como leitura de teclado e limpeza de tela, de quebra o código fica portátil

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).